# Regex command to get string after second space

Tags: regex, command

I have input as below :

```
Investments Total : 47,842.87 48,901.25 1,042.22 49,943.47 99.9794 2,100.60 2,100.60 0.00 0.00 0
Investments Total : 47,842.87 16,901.25 1,042.22 49,943.47 99.9794 2,100.60 2,100.60 0.00 0.00 0
```

and output target is

```
48,901.25
16,901.25
```

Meaning to get second space value after `Investments Total :`

I did try using below command

```
(?<=Investments Total :)\s\S+
```

but the outcome is first value after space.

Comment: It depends on the supported language or tool, but `(?<=Investments Total :\s\S+\s)\S+` https://regex101.com/r/sZz984/1 or with a capture group `Investments Total :\s\S+\s(\S+)` https://regex101.com/r/PHpxOw/1/

Comment: Thank for the help manage to get the output from the command using the command (?<=Investments Total :\s\S+\s)\S+

Comment: That's _still_ not a "command". A command like `grep` might make sense here, but we can only speculate about what you are actually using (and that particular regex would not work with plain `grep`; though if you have GNU `grep`, it could work with `grep -P`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
(?<=Investments Total :\s\S+\s)\S+
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?<=` Positive lookbehind, assert what is to the left is

  - `Investments Total :` Match literally
  - `\s\S+\s` Match a whitespace char, 1+ non whitespace chars and a whitspace char
- `)` Close lookbehind
- `\S+` Match 1+ non whitespace chars

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zh7y3N/1)